# Refresh an image in Rebol

Tags: user-interface, web, rebol

I've been working on this for a while. Gone through the REBOL docs and the answers here, but I am stumped. Can someone please tell me how to get an REBOL GUI image to update to another image? Here's the code I've gotten after two days of hacking at it. Any help would he appreciated.

```
REBOL [
    Title: "Yvonne View"
]

yvonne: func[] [
    parts: probe parse read http://pics.mytrapster.com/yvonne.php {="}
    load to-string parts/6    
]

img1: to-image (load-image yvonne)
img2: to-image (load-image yvonne)

v1: layout [
    size 500x500
    b: image img1
    btn "Refresh" [ b: img2 ]
    btn "Quit" [quit]
]

view v1
```

The url loads. The quit button works. The "b" variable just doesn't clear and update.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you can update an image is by using `set-face`

Change the refresh button line to:

```
 btn "Refresh" [set-face b img2]
```

Alternatively if you are manually changing a pane of a face, you can use `show` (i.e. `show b`)

Comment: I corrected myself.  `show` is not necessary when using `set-face`